# Should I compile Near Core and Nearup to participate in stakewars?

Tags: nearprotocol, nearprotocol-validator

I can not compile Near Core and Nearup. Can I use other installations like docker or nearup Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes, you can use precompiled binary or docker through [nearup](https://github.com/near/nearup/).

Take a look at the [nearup](https://github.com/near/nearup/) documentation to see how to run a near node using different setups.

- **Run with Docker**: `nearup betanet`
- **Run without docker**: `nearup betanet --nodocker`. This will download and use a precompiled binary for your platform if it exists.
- **Run from source code**:

Download source code from [github repository](https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearcore) and checkout to `beta` branch (this is the one used in stakewars, and it doesn't need to be compatible with `master` branch).

Compile source code using `make release` from the `nearcore` folder. I see you fail at this point, probably because you were missing to install some dependencies. In Ubuntu install them with:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y git binutils-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev zlib1g-dev libdw-dev libiberty-dev cmake gcc g++ python docker.io protobuf-compiler
```

To run this binary use:

```
nearup betanet --nodocker --binary-path nearcore/target/release
```